# Reactive mapping after checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm new to shiny and leaflet and I would appreciate any pointers. The code below is an attempt to map points over a base map. It works, but not reactively.
The points come from a data frame (imported from CSV), which I can map. However, at the top of the app, I created a checkbox to let the user choose features. The idea is that selection will determine which rows are passed forwards, and therefore which points are mapped. This is the step I'm struggling with. In the code, I'm now passing the full list of possible points from the data frame, not from the output of the filtering (checkbox input). How do I pass the result of the filtering process instead?

My approach is to grab the cols with coordinates to create a data frame with `cbind()`, passing this to `points`; but perhaps one could pass the relevant cols from the filtered data directly. Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)


parks <- read.csv("data.csv")

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  # First row for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "d_Governorate",
                              label = "Governorate:",
                              choices = c("All",
                                          unique(as.character(parks$Governorate))),
                              selected = "All"
                              )
    ),

    leafletOutput("d_map")
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$d_Governorate != "", 'Please choose at least one feature.')
    )
    temp <- select(parks, lon, lat)
    if (input$d_Governorate != "All") {
      temp <- filter(parks, Governorate %in% input$d_Governorate) %>% 
        select(lon, lat)
    }
    temp
  }),

  output$d_map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

DATA:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nq07fbyurur8ec/data.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the part where you define the point reactive variable with the following code (the code uses the dplyr package):

```
        points <- reactive({
            validate(
                    need(input$d_Governorate != "", 'Please choose at least one feature.')
            )
            temp <- select(parks, lon, lat)
            if (input$d_Governorate != "All") {
                    temp <- filter(parks, Governorate %in% input$d_Governorate) %>% 
                            select(lon, lat)
            }
            temp
    })
```

In the UI part add the:

```
selected = "All"
```

to the checkboxGroupInput definition.

Comment: Thanks @Valter. I added the code as you suggest. What is working is a refresh at every user input. But it always maps all points. In other words, the filtering is not working. I tried passing temp to points: `points <- temp` , replacing your last statement `temp`, but to no avail.

Comment: @jpinelo I have checked the code and to me it looks fine. I have deployed the app here: [app](https://altervalter.shinyapps.io/q11app/) Check the table below the map to see which points are marked on the map.